# How to compare the values inside if using logical operators in the bash shell script

Tags: bash, shell, scripting

I have below shell script code :

```
if [ [ "$prevState" != "\"CANCELED\""] || ["$prevState" = "\"CANCELED\"" & "$1" = "YES" ] ]
```

where prevstate has value CANCELED and $1 has value NO. But in the shell execution I am getting the below error.

```
/dir/checks/Check.sh: 30: [: /dir/checks/Check.sh: 30: /dir/checks/Check.sh: missing ]NO: not found
```

How to compare inside if in the shell script using logical AND and OR operators. All variable in the above condition are strings

Comment: Were you following any bash tutorial? What have you found when researching how to use logical AND and OR? `All variable in the above condition are strings` Shell has only string variables, there are no other.

Comment: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/basic-operators-in-shell-scripting/

Comment: I tried this. This showed to use it as above

Comment: Well, there are no string comparisons explained there... After reading some pages, there are problems with this introduction. Take a peek at [bash guide](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/TestsAndConditionals).

Comment: That geeksforgeeks site is just plain wrong. Please do not use it. `if(($a == "true" & $b == "true" ))` is not doing anything related to the explanation provided there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The construct of `if` is:

```
if some_command
then
     # this is executed, if `some_command` returned with 0 exit status
     some_other_command
fi
```

And it's not <strike>`if [ expression ]`</strike>. The `[` is a normal program, executable, equivalent to `test` executable. The *program* `[` exits with a 0 exit status  when the expression *evaluated within the program `[`* is determinated to be true. You can do `if /usr/bin/[ "a" = "b" ]` with the same result as `if [ "a" = "b" ]`.

With `&&` and `||` you can "chain" different commands - it's called a *list* of commands. The exit status in the list is the exit status of the last executed command. `&&` runs the right command when the left one returned with exit status 0. `||` runs the command on the right when the left one returned with exit status different then 0. Note that commands in a list are executed in order - `a || b && c` is `(a || b) && c` and *not* <strike>`a || (b && c)`</strike>.

You can try:

```
# if
#     prevState is not \"CANCELED\" _including the quotes_
#         or
#      first argument is "YES"
# then

if [ "$prevState" != "\"CANCELED\"" ] || [ "$1" = "YES" ] ; then
      blabla
fi
```

Links: [bash manual list of commands](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Lists), [bash manual conditional constructs](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Conditional-Constructs), [posix test](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/test.html)